# Set own variable in js style object

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I want to submit my own variable in the style object. I will show you what I mean:

```
var example = background
element.style.example // example is equal to the variable up top
```

Is there any with of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to define the property to be set dynamically, you could use the following approach:

```
var example = 'background';
element.style[example] = 'black';
```

[More on how to access object properties on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer, didn't know this was possible in JS. I tried `style{example}` and `style(example)` but I needed the `[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket notation

```
var example = "background";
element.style[example] = "#fff";
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a quick answer